# Combinations Proof

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

Show that $2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni$.

I tried expanding $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni$ into sum of: $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$, and found the common ratio and then used the sum formula, but I did not get to $2^n$.

Comment: Nevermind, may u plz help me with the question

Comment: @Alex that is rude.

Comment: @mathhelpplzzz there is no need to respond asking for help. If people choose to help they will.

Comment: Can you guess what was the first link I got from searching on Google "binomial coefficient proof"?  This link: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM4.pdf.  Sometimes, it saves a lot of time to find a proof on your own.

Comment: @Alex : "LaTeX" is a misnomer for what is used here.  It's actually MathJax.  If you master MathJax and think you've mastered LaTeX, you're in for a shock when you encounter actual LaTeX. $\qquad$

Comment: This sequence of numbers does not have a common ratio.  That is the mistake in your attempted solution. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yeah whatever

Answer (score 3):

Consider the expansion of $(x+1)^n$. This looks like:
$$ x^n + nx^{n-1} + \cdots + nx + 1$$

So how do we get the coefficients of the intermediate terms? They are just the number of different way to choose $k\; x$ terms (and $n-k\; 1$ terms) out of the $n$ brackets $(x+1)\cdots(x+1)$. So 
$$(x+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^k$$

Now set $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Try expanding $2^n = (1+1)^n$ using the Binomial Formula. Do you notice any simularities between your problem and this expansion?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand the similarity. Is it related to the summation?

Comment: @mathhelpplzzz Do you know how to expand a binom using the Binomial Formula? For example note that:

$$(1+1)^2 = 1 + 2 + 1$$
$$(1+1)^3 = 1 + 3 + 3 + 1$$
$$(1+1)^4 = 1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1$$

Do the coefficients remind you of something?

Comment: Yes the exponents are the same as the second number in each expression

Comment: @mathhelpplzzz Not really what I meant. Anyway it's seems that you're not familiar with the Binomial Formula. Note that these numbers are the rows in the Pascal's Triangle. Additionally the binomial theorem states that:

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^{n-i}y^{i}$$

Now just substitute $x=y=1$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you also just use induction over $n$, so 
$$
2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni \tag1
$$
clearly holds for $n=1$ (*or even for $n=0$*), since
$$
2^1=\sum_{i=0}^1 \binom 1i=\binom 10+\binom11=1+1=2
$$
Now we want to show that
$$
2^{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}i
$$
holds by using our assumption $(1)$. We have by using the Pascal identity
$$
{n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-1 \choose k}
$$ 
to show the following
$$
2^{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}i=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigg(\binom {n}{i-1}+\binom {n}{i}\bigg)+1
$$
which gives us 
\begin{align}
1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom {n}{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom {n}{i}+1&=\binom nn+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom {n}{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom {n}{i}+\binom n0\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \binom {n}{i-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom {n}{i}\tag 2\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom {n}{i}+\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom {n}{i}=2^n+2^n=2^{n+1} \tag3
\end{align}
while we used an index shift in $(2)$ and our induction assumption in $(3)$. So we eventually proved by induction
$$
2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Use binomial theorem**

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

Choose $$x=y=1$$ to get

$$(1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 1^k 1^{n-k}$$

---

**Method 2: Use induction**

1. Prove $$2^0 = \sum_{k=0}^{0} \binom{0}{k}$$
2. Prove for n=1,2,...

$$2^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \to 2^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$$

This comes down to proving

$$2\binom{n-1}{0} + ... + 2\binom{n-1}{n-1} = \binom{n}{0} + ... + \binom{n}{n}$$

---

**Method 3: Use counting argument**

Consider creating a sandwich having to decide which of $n$ items you're going to include.

Say item 1 is lettuce. item 2 is tomato. item 3 is patty. item 4 is ketchup and so on until item n is cheese.

You could go through each item and decide whether or not to add it (2 choices per item). By the multiplication rule of counting, the number ways to do this is $2^n$.

That's the LHS. As for the RHS,

you can choose none out of the n items. You can choose one of the n items. You can choose two of the n items. So on until you can choose n of the n items.

Since these are mutually exclusive cases, by the addition rule of counting, the number of ways to do this is:

$$\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ... + \binom{n}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the identities

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n+1}{r} &= \binom{n}{r-1} + \binom{n}{r}&&(1\le r \le n)\\
\binom{n}0 &= \binom{n}{n} = 1
\end{align*}$$

and prove by induction that your result is true for all integers $n\ge 0$:

$$
\sum^{n+1}_{r=0}\binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n+1}0 + \sum^{n}_{r=1}\binom{n+1}{r} + \binom{n+1}{n+1}
$$